# How can I create a rule for a thing using the aws iot java sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am trying to create a rule without using the UI provided by AWS but using the java sdk. Looking over the codes of the java sdk I have not seen any codes that creates rule. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After painful research and posting questions in aws forum, I have found out that there is no way you can create a custom rule gui by installing it from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java) but you have to follow [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) approach .You can find how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100229/5782310)

Here are some docs that may help you as well
[link 1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/iot/AWSIotClient.html#createTopicRule-com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.CreateTopicRuleRequest-)
[link 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/iot/AWSIotClient.html)