# How do i install the aws sdk in play framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, sbt

I know that I can install a dependency like this `libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs,  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.38" )`

but the problem with this approach is that it will install all the unnecessary dependencies. I just want to install one specific dependency as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) using the BOM way. How can i do that in play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the aws-sdk-core and rest of the required modules individually.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs,  
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.43",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.43"
)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of that way. Thanks again